# Problam with views and template in Django - show data in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a problam in Django. I'm a amature Django developer. I can't show my "Category" data in Template. here is my code :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = TaggableManager ()
    cats = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from blog.models import Category

render(request, 'index.html', args)

def cats(request):
    t = get_template('category.html')
    for i in Category.object.get :
        html = t.render(Context({'cat': i}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post, Category

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(
            queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:2],
            template_name="index.html")),       
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$',DetailView.as_view(
            model = Post,
            template_name="post.html")),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$','cats'),

)
```

**A part of template "post.html"**

```
#some html code here

   {% include "category.html" %}

#another some html code here
```

**This is my category.html**

```
<li><a href="#">{{cat}}</a></li>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should, first, get a better understanding of how things work by going through the official Django tutorial. Seriously, there are so many mistakes in your code. For instance, it's not `Category.object.get`, it is `Category.objects.get(title=title)`. And that `for` loop won't work there. So, I suppose, you need to learn Python before Django. And a lot more mistakes I won't point out but you will eventually know if you go through Django tut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of writing code is not quite correct. Views are meant for backend codes, urls.py is meant only for url specifications not for writing queries.

views.py

`from blog.models import Category
 from blog.models import Post

 def cats(request):
     queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:2]
     return render_to_response('category.html',{'queryset': queryset},
         context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

add this in urls.py

`url(r'^cats', 'blog.views.cats', name='cats')`

In `category.html` you can access any field of the object that is passed from views.py (here `queryset` )

`<li><a href="#">{{querset.title}}</a></li>`